# JQuery dialog update data in table automatically when I finish with changes

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have JSP page that contains table. when I click on one row of table initiate JQuery dialog with data from that row inside dialog. I can change data and when I click on button application save data into DB.

I want to refresh that row with new data when I write data to DB. Now I need to press F5 to do it.

Is there any javascript function to do it automatically when I update DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to write you own code to do that. You could add a function to the dialog's `close` event and pass all new values and a row ID to it. This function then updates the given row via JS (using JQuery).

Comment: definitelly I need to write my own code, all things I found on internet spoke about refreshing whole table not only the row.

Answer (score 1):

No. HTTP is a request-response protocol. The client has to request something to get it. You could poll the server every X seconds to get changes. Or use something like [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), but it would probably be overkill.

But what you can do is trigger a refresh of the page or of the table in JavaScript once the save action has been done, to reload the data from the DB. You just won't get changes done by other users of the application.

Answer (score 0):

```
function doUpdate(id,codice,descrizione,descrBreve,colore) {
        var i = 1;

        $('#row_' + id).children().each(function(){ 
            var kid = $(this); 

            if (i==2){
                kid.text(codice);
            }
            if (i==3){
                kid.text(descrizione);
            }
            if (i==4){
                kid.text(descrBreve);
            }
            if (i==5){
                 $(this).find(':first-child').css('background-color', colore); 
            }
            if (i==6){
                kid.text(colore);
            }
            i= i + 1;
        });
```

This is the function if anyone need it for update only one row of table without refresh...